# Default naming of dropped controls in Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo

When I add new controls on my Form at design-time, Delphi gives them default names. `TLabel` controls will be named as `'Label1'`, `'Label2'`, etc.

I created my own component class: `tMyLabel`. Note the lowercase `t`.  Delphi names these controls as `'tMyLabel1'`, `'tMyLabel2'`, etc. I don't want the 't' at the beginning.

I realize that it has something to do with the class name. Delphi seems to be case sensitive in this situation.

If I rename my class to `TMyLabel`, then all works well.

Why is Delphi case sensitive in this matter? Can I persuade Delphi to make no distinction between `'tMyLabel'` and `'TMyLabel'`?

I use Delphi 10.2.3, but Delphi has behaved this way for years.

Edit (2018-04-30):
Ken asked for a code

```
    unit MySpeedButton;

    interface

    uses
      SysUtils, Classes, Controls, Vcl.Graphics, Buttons;

    type
      tMySpeedButtonProps = class(TPersistent)
      private
        fParent      : pointer      ;
        constructor Create( pParent : pointer );
        destructor  Destroy; override;
      end;

    type
      tMySpeedButton = class( TSpeedButton )
      private
        fMyProps      : tMySpeedButtonProps  ;
      protected
        procedure    Click ; override;
      public
        function  GetCanvas: TCanvas;                 //Allow access to the Canvas            procedure Paint ; override ;
        constructor Create( AOwner : TComponent ); override;
        destructor  Destroy; override;
      published
        property TM : tMySpeedButtonProps read fMyProps write fMyProps;
      end;

    procedure Register;

    implementation

    uses
      Forms, Windows;

    constructor tMySpeedButtonProps.Create( pParent : pointer );
    begin
      inherited Create;
      fParent  := pParent ;
    end;

    destructor tMySpeedButtonProps.Destroy;
    begin
      inherited Destroy;
    end;

    constructor tMySpeedButton.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
    begin
      fMyProps := tMySpeedButtonProps.Create( self );
      inherited Create(AOwner);

    {$ifdef RegisterFormular }
    {$endif}
    end;

    destructor tMySpeedButton.destroy;
    begin
      fMyProps.Free;
      inherited destroy;
    end;

    procedure tMySpeedButton.Click ;
    begin
      inherited Click;
    end;

    procedure tMySpeedButton.Paint ;
    begin
      inherited Paint;
    end;

    function tMySpeedButton.GetCanvas: TCanvas;
    begin
      Result:= Canvas;
    end;

    procedure Register;
    begin
      RegisterComponents( 'Test' , [ tMySpeedButton ] );
    end;

    end.
```

After I compile & register `tMySpeedButton` I get the unwanted names starting with a 't'.

Comment: Delphi (language) is not case sensitive. This thing is. Why? Because somebody decided so? :) Similarly with the `Register` procedure. That one must be with capital too.

Comment: Usually case sensitive parts of Delphi are because of the need to be compatible with C++Builder.

Comment: Yet, if you don't want to follow (recommended) rule of capitalizing `T`ype names, you can use IDE experts like e.g. CnWizards that has an automatic component naming tool (I believe it's possible to setup case insensitive pattern there; can check that if you were interested).

Comment: I used CnWizards years ago but it was causing some problems.(not sure anymore what it was) So I removed it.

Comment: You could disable everything but the component naming one.

Comment: GExpert also contains a similar tool. (CnWizards originally took that functionality from GExperts AFAIK).

Comment: Delphi is not case-sensitive, with a single exception. That exception is the name of the `Register` procedure used to register components, and the only reason it is case-sensitive is for compatibility with C++Builder. Delphi's standard (and that of the vast majority of Delphi developers, component libraries, and most of the rest of the world that uses a derivative of Turbo Pascal) is to preface type names with an uppercase `T`, as in `TLabel`, `TForm`, and so forth. Delphi has done so since version 1.0 was released, and continues to do so today.

Comment: (continued) Delphi also does not produce the behavior you describe, and I use dozens of in-house created components that behave properly - a label with a classname of `TMyLabel` becomes `MyLabel1`, and a quick test shows that a class of `tMyLabel` still becomes `MyLabel1` when dropped on a form.  Please provide a [mcve] (a sample component source file that can be copied/pasted into the IDE, placed into a package, and compiled) that demonstrates the issue. My suspicion is that you've named your class something differently by mistake (like `TtMyLabel`).

Comment: @Ken: I had already withdrawn my comment. <g>

Comment: @Ken: I edited my question and added code